# Form validator and submit handler is not getting called

Tags: 7, forms

I've created a Form using my module, which looks like [this](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/512.txt), then I've created a _validate & _submit handler (please see the linked file above). Then, in my front page, I printed the form using:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_signin');
print render($form);
```

But when I'm submitting the form, the validate & submit handlers are not getting called, I'm getting redirected back to the front page. However, I created a submit button but when I was clicking it, ***the form was not getting submitted***, so I submitted the form using jQuery's `.submit()` method to submit the function!

Can anyone help me why the form was not getting submitted first time, and finally when it was submitted *(using javascript)* the handler was not getting called? [Here](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/513.txt) goes the template file I used to render the form.

**PS.** I created an entry in the `hook_menu()` and when I submit form using this page, the form gets submitted (calls validate handler). But it is **not** calling validate/submit handler when I submit it in my front page. :(

Comment: Please show your form, validate and submite functions.

Comment: Can you add this piece of code after printing the form and check ?`<?php
                               print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
                               print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
                               print drupal_render($form['form_token']);
                               ?>` This worked in 6 for me I cannot test it on 7

Comment: @BetaRide I've provided them, please check the links...
@kantu They're printed using `drupal_render_children();`

Comment: Might want to try it on a normal node page as well and see what result you get. There could be problems when the front page is not properly set or something important is missing.

Comment: @Dooshta it works in normal pages. It just doesn't work when I try to get it in front page using `drupal_get_form()`

Comment: please paste your code here. Please share the functions form, validate function and submit function

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have an element of type `submit` in your form function.

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain what's wrong with this answer ?

Comment: OK, read the sentence about the submit button. Still, the form not being submitted when clicking the button is not a normal behaviour, and submitting via JQuery will only complicate the problem.

Comment: #submit adds a submit-handler function, right? I had one, (commented on my code now) but no luck! I think the down-voter will explain...

Comment: `#submit`at the form level does what you say, but I was talking about a submit button `'#type' => 'submit'`.

Comment: As per what Countzero said... Dont know if it defaults without it being set but try:

$form['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Submit'), 
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_dum_s'),
    '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE);
 }

Comment: [Here is the part of the doc page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#submit) refering to what I was trying to explain .

Comment: I tried them all, no luck still. @Countzero dont worry about the downvote, I'm making it even

Comment: I'd first try to make the form behave normally in a normal situation : mean, call it via a menu hook, submit it with a submit button, and see if everything's right. If it's not, then you'll be sure it comes from elsewhere than your unusual implementation. Shorter version : do everything by the book, test, then try sorcery ;-).